# how to check which app is using internet , camera and mic in background in android app?

Tags: java, android, service, camera, background-foreground

how to check which app/packages is using internet, camera, and mic in the background? basically, I want to develop an app which checks the background running app, is that any app which is using internet,  mic, and camera in background and giver user an option to close that app? any solution in android studio..?

Comment: In general, this is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: can you guide me for rooted device..?